# Select last measure date for each ID at the same work date

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a table like the next one and I would like to obtain the last "measure date" for every "Work date" of a same "ID".

[image]

At the end I would like to have this result:

[image]

In that example, the last two rows of the initial table disappears in the final one because I just want the last "To do" measure entered in the table for every work date of a same ID.

As you see in the first table, for a same ID I can have 2 differents measure_date for a same work date. However I need only the last measure date a same work date by ID. In that case, I need to get the last measure date to get the good "To Do" to achieve my job .

The table can have a lot of different Work Date and 100 of ID, which are the same for every Work date.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this in mySQL, Excel, or MS SQL Server?

Comment: In excel you would use and Index/Match function with Max(IF()).

Comment: I used SQL to bring some data from a server to an Excel files. Thank you

Comment: Which is the relevant tag?

Answer (score -1):

From what I read the query should go something like this,

```
SELECT id, work_date, max(measure_date), todo FROM tablename GROUP BY id, work_date;
```

But notice that the todo value will be quite random (or can have unexpected results) so leave it out from the query. But like with the comments, there is not enough information and it does look like excel.

Comment: Thank you but it's not working...maybe my explanation wasn't clear enough.

As you see in the first table, for a same ID I can have 2 differents measure_date for a same work date. However I need only the last measure date for a same work date by ID. In that case, I need to get the last measure date to get the good "To Do" to achieve my job .